# Append to list for every proxy?

Tags: javascript, json, fs

For every proxy I have in this list I split it and need to append it to an array in a file.

I have tried this but only one proxy gets added out of 5:

```
function saveProxies() {
    const fs = require("fs")

    let proxies = document.getElementById("proxies").value.split(/\r?\n/)

    // for(i = 0; i < proxies.length; i++) {
    //     await doo(proxies[i])
    // }

    proxies.forEach(proxy => {
        // doo(proxy)
        let p1 = `${proxy.split(":")[0]}:${proxy.split(":")[1]}`
        let p2 = proxy.split(":")[2]
        let p3 = proxy.split(":")[3]

        fs.readFile("views/proxies.json", (err, data) => {
            let arr = JSON.parse(data)

            arr.push({
                address: p1,
                username: p2,
                password: p3
            })

            fs.writeFile("views/proxies.json", JSON.stringify(arr), (err) => {})
        })


    })
}
```

Comment: Try `fs.appendFile` instead

Comment: @Nuhman the content of the file is JSON. Appending anything to a JSON produces a string that is not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

[`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) is asynchronous and your code does not wait for it to complete before processing next proxy. In consequence, for each proxy, the code reads the initial file in memory, change the data structure (add one entry) then write it back into the file. The last call to `fs.writeFile()` that completes decides the content of the file.

A simple solution is to use [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) and [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options). This way there is no asynchronous processing, for each proxy the code reads the actual content of the file and updates it before the processing of the next proxy.

**But this solution is not efficient!** There is no point to read (and parse) the content of the file again, the data used to write the file already exists in memory.

The correct solution is to read the file once, update the data in memory for all proxies then write it back in file.

The synchronous version could look like this:

```
const fs = require("fs")

let proxies = document.getElementById("proxies").value.split(/\r?\n/)
let filepath = "views/proxies.json";

function saveProxies(proxies, filepath) {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(filepath)
    let arr = JSON.parse(data)

    proxies.forEach((proxy) => {
        let pieces = proxy.split(':')
        arr.push({
            address: `${pieces[0]}:${pieces[1]}`,
            username: pieces[2],
            password: pieces[3]
        })
    })

    fs.writeFileSync(filepath, JSON.stringify(arr))
}
```

You should also handle the errors (the file does not exist or it is not readable/writable, its content is not a valid JSON etc).